# Javascript for Microsoft CRM 2011 ELSE/IF

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to customize certain fields on a Contact form in MS Dynamics CRM. Basically we have 3 addresses; 1 correspondence address which takes the values of the private or the work address. What I would like to achieve is that, if you set our field manually to "no address available", a pop-up is shown informing us that we have some data in either the P or W address:

I am trying to get the values first and then check them if they contain some values. It is only one function. I am definitely a beginner, so any input is appreciated. :)

This is how I tried it:

```
function CheckKorrespondenzAdresse() {
    var korrespondenzadresse1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_correspondece_adress").getValue(); //get the Koresspondenzadresse value
    var pplz = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_address3_postalcode").getValue(); //get the P-PLZ value 
    var port = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_address3_city").getValue(); //get the P-Ort value 
    var gplz = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address2_postalcode").getValue(); //get the G-PLZ value
    var gort = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address2_city").getValue(); //get the G-Ort value

    if (korrespondenzadresse1 == '100000002' | pplz != null |  port != null) {
        confirm("P Adresse enthält Daten! Korrespondenzadresse wird darum auf Privatadresse geändert!"); //User benachrichtigen, dass Feld Daten enthält
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_correspondece_adress").setValue(100000000); //Korrespondenzadresse auf Privatadresse ändern
    }
    else if (korrespondenzadresse1 == '100000002' | gplz != null | gort != null) {
         confirm("G Adresse enthält Daten! Korrespondenzadresse wird darum auf Geschäftsadresse geändert!"); //User benachrichtigen, dass Feld Daten enthält
         Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_correspondece_adress").setValue(100000001); //Korrespondenzadresse auf Geschäftsadresse ändern
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the option values in `new_correspondece_adress` represent? Do not use the `|` operator; always use `||` instead. '|' is a bitwise operator that is used in binary arithmetic.

Comment: Hey Henk van Boeijen, thanks a lot for your input. the values in `new_correspondece_adress` represent the different adresses, which should be chosen for a correspondence adress of a person in the CRM. Either the private adress (100'000'000) or the work adress (100'000'000). the third value is chosen, when neither adress is filled out in the work or the privat adress section (100'000'000).

Comment: Does this work when you changed to or operators? Looking at the code I get a feeling that you want to change the first "||" to a "&&" and then place the plz/ort in a parenthesis so you are asking if the correspondance address is set to "...2" AND (postal code OR city is not empty), or the other way around, optionset is ...2 OR (postal code AND city is not empty). With ORs all the way the logic looks weird at least :)

Comment: Yes, if i change it to && it is working! Thanks a lot for all the help. Had a mistake in my logic there.
Have a great day everyone :)